# Elevation profiles approximation with polynomials/splines

Tags: polynomials, approximation, spline, python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7lye.jpg)I am to approximate natural ground elevation profiles with a mathematical function. Let say the elevation profiles can be approximated with `n^2` degree of polynomials. In my case 5th or 6th degree would work quite ok. 
Then an approximate embankment should be fund which is a good representation of the terrain. 
My question is, how to mathematically define/find the appropriate embankment function? 
The same should work for valleys as well.

[image]

Comment: See the link for a draft image about the question

Comment: I`m getting somewhere with first and second derivatives, but still not sure how to find the most descriptive slopes.